# What happens to Atom KE when it's supressed by other forces?

Tags: energy, atomic-physics, kinetic-theory

Assume fallowing situation:

1. Atom 1 travels in direction of Atom 2 with velocity (kinetic energy) vy.
2. As Atom 1 gets closer to Atom 2, the Atom 2 repealing forces have more impact on Atom 1.
3. At some point Atom 1 will stop and lose all its initial kinetic energy.
4. Atom 1 will be pushed back now by Atom repealing forces.

Question is- where did the Initial KE of Atom1 go? According laws of Physics, energy can not be created or destroyed, but transferred from one form to another.

One theory is that it's converted into Potential Energy. But potential energy, as I understood, is not something that actually happens to the system (physically), but is rather a mathematical tool to do some next phase predictions.

Another is that is transformed into heat. But that doesn't apply on atomic level as Heat is atoms KE (movement) measurement?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Whenever there is a tendency or capacity for a particle to do some work, we can say it has potential energy. While potential energy is a mathematical tool, it's not imaginary. It's there. It is stored in the system, and can be expended for kinetic energy in the future. Energy has not disappeared, as by definition of energy, these atoms have forces acting on them and can be displaced by these forces.

Comment: SO what is your answer to the main question "where did the Initial KE of Atom1 go?"

Comment: The initial KE didn't 'go' anywhere, it simply got converted to another form of mechanical energy as a result of the Coulomb force between them that has the capacity to displace the atom(as ENERGY SHOULD), which will eventually get converted to KE again. This energy is called PE. Energy cannot just go anywhere, it can only be transferred to other particles or be converted to other forms. It is the forces that are carried by the bosons(although I don't have sufficient info on that subject), that actually travel.

Comment: So one can say that Atom1 has infinite (< speed of light I guess) PE storage, because it can be kicked any time by another atom and gain velocity. This doesn't make sense for me. It was stopped by atom 2 repealing and lost inital it's velocity (KE energy). For big objects this is always converted to heat, for atom world there needs to be another explanation.

Comment: Alright then, let's think about big objects in that case. When these big objects are directed towards each other, you say that they lose their kinetic energy to heat energy. Then tell me, after they have lost their kinetic energy to heat, do they regain it? No. This is because total energy is still conserved in the system. After these objects have lost their energy to non-conservative forces like friction, they don't have any energy left to regain the same kinetic energy; hence, you can say that they don't have any 'potential' to regain that velocity, ergo, they don't have potential energy.

Comment: You are correct about saying that atoms themselves don't release heat, but it's because there are no non-conservative forces acting on the atoms that do negative work on the system, there is ONLY the Coulomb force. Since there 'is' no force that will make the atoms lose their mechanical energy to the surroundings, all the kinetic energy can take on only one other form after all of it has been converted when the atoms stop; that is the potential energy due to the tendency of being repelled.

Comment: Classical examples like ball lift and your coliding example can be perfectly explained by totally excluding  PE so for me it's not real at all. But neat mathematical took to make predictions.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112441/discussion-between-trshmanx-and-reet-jaiswal).